# Why is OpenCV_FOUND set to false?

Tags: opencv, cmake, installation, ubuntu-16.04

To start off, I know this question has too many duplicates, but none of them work in my case.

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.13.2 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.  I followed the installation instructions outlined here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/.  As per step#6 mentioned therein, I could confirm that OpenCV was installed successfully.

However, when I try to run `cmake ..` while building this project: https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades/, I get an error saying:

> Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your
>     configuration.
>
> You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
>     library.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
>     Found package configuration file:
>
> /home/abhishek/opencv-2.4.13.2/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake
>
> but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
>     NOT FOUND.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/abhishek/opencv-2.4.13.2/vehicle_detection_haarcascades/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

As mentioned in other SO answers, I tried deleting the cache files, reinstalling, reinstalling in a different directory, etc., but none of them works.  So, how can I overcome this error?  I am going to use this vehicle detection project (developed majorly in C++) in an academic setting and I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: You need to run `cmake ..` with other params like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX `

Comment: Have you tried to do what `cmake` tells you to do? `You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.`

Comment: If you had this problem when working with Android projects, take care of your `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 3):

Some background information on when and how `OpenCV_FOUND` is set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

*Note*: The code of `OpenCVConfig.cmake` does vary through the OpenCV versions but the general functionality more or less kept the same. I've reviewed [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) version 3.2.0 and crosschecked against version 2.4.10 for this answer:

1. Those things are handled in the [`find_package_handle_standard_args()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html) call in [`OpenCVConfig.cmake`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in)

   > ```
   > find_package_handle_standard_args(OpenCV REQUIRED_VARS OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH
   >                                   VERSION_VAR OpenCV_VERSION ${_OpenCV_FPHSA_ARGS})
   > ```

   If one of the `REQUIRED_VARS` could not be determined (is not set) or the version given in `VERSION_VAR` does not match, then `OpenCV_FOUND` is set to `FALSE`.
2. The `OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH` is directly put in the CMake config during the [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) build:

   > ```
   > get_filename_component(OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH "${OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH}/@OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH_RELATIVE_CONFIGCMAKE@" REALPATH)
   > ```

   So this is unlikely to fail, if the config script itself was found.

   **But be aware** that absolute paths could be in the resulting config file. So don't move it around or manually install it. So you should check `/home/abhishek/opencv-2.4.13.2/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake` for invalid/not matching paths.
3. The `OpenCV_VERSION` is checked against whatever is given in the project's `find_package(OpenCV [version] ...)` call as `version`.

   But [`vehicle_detection_haarcascades/CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) doesn`t specify a specific version:

   > ```
   > find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
   > ```
4. The `${_OpenCV_FPHSA_ARGS}` will put a `HANDLE_COMPONENTS` there for CMake version >= 2.8.8. This would additionally check the `COMPONENTS` given in a `find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS ...)` call.

   But that's also not applicable here (see above).
5. Last the `find_package()` call itself can set `OpenCV_FOUND` to `FALSE` if it didn't find the necessary [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) configuration files.

   But this seems not to be the case here since your error names the path where it did find the config script.

**References**

- [`Install-OpenCV`](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV) did the trick of correctly installing [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) on my Ubuntu installation

Answer (score 3):

After wasting hours on this problem several times, I've decided to post what solved my problem for future reference, in case I forget again 3 months later. 
Suppose the OpenCV installation is correct, I didn't need to manually set $OpenCV_FOUND, I didn't need to touch any files in the OpenCV installation folder (/home/.../opencv-3.1.0/{build,cmake}/), the only things I needed to do were:

1. set $OpenCV_DIR in my 'CMakeLists.txt' by 
    `set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/")` or 
    `set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/.../opencv-3.1.0/build/")`
2. Delete the 'build' folder **in the application that I was developing**, create a new 'build' folder, and run `cmake ..` etc. inside it. 
   This problem usually happens when I've messed around with the "CMakeLists.txt" that contains the `FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Ubuntu 16.04, have you tried the packaged OpenCV? I don't have 16.04 handy, but detection works fine with 15.10.

```
[zinc:~/q] lsb_release -sa
No LSB modules are available.
Ubuntu
Ubuntu 15.10
15.10
wily
[zinc:~/q] dpkg --get-selections cmake libopencv-dev
cmake                       install
libopencv-dev                   install
[zinc:~/q] cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

include(CMakePrintHelpers)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
cmake_print_variables(OpenCV_LIBS)
[zinc:~/q] cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- OpenCV_LIBS="opencv_videostab;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_photo;opencv_ocl;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_legacy;opencv_imgproc;opencv_highgui;opencv_gpu;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_contrib;opencv_calib3d"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nega/q
[zinc:~/q]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question.  I wish to know all the possible reasons why this error crosses up.

Comment: If that's the case, then you need to rephrase your original question.

Answer (score 1):

If everything goes well until step 6 with no errors, i think the problem that might be causing this error to show is the fact that you are not working on the virtual environment so I think this should help :
open terminal -> type: workon cv -> the execute the cmake